# How to copy files as templates, injecting values to them, to a different folder?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, fs, yeoman-generator

I used this library, `mem-fs-editor` (https://github.com/sboudrias/mem-fs-editor), in a Yeoman generator a few weeks ago. It worked nicely, but now I tried to use it again in a different scope and I couldn't do anything. **Obs**: I used it because this is the library Yeoman provides to handle the file system.

In Yeoman Generators we can copy files from a template folder, passing values to inject in the code, to a different folder. And that's precisely what I need, but I can't use Yeoman this time.

I tried the same code I used in my Yo Generator, but it don't work. So I'm not sure how `mem-fs` works. No errors are thrown and even the code provided by the author of the project don't work to me.

I tried this (and some other things with copyTpl) with no success

```
var memFs = require('mem-fs');
var editor = require('mem-fs-editor');

var store = memFs.create();
var fs = editor.create(store);

console.log(fs.write('./somefile.js', 'var a = 1;'));
```

Anyone knows how it works or what else I can do to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

mem-fs-editor author here.

mem-fs stands for memory file-system. All the files you creates are stored in memory and won't get written to disk until you call:

```
editor.commit(callback);
```

Yeoman does that automatically for you. It is this way with Yeoman to collide every file changes together and then being able to only prompt for file conflicts once (rather than everytime a single file is being written to).